# Creating a ef6 dbcontext constructor class

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm trying to create a helper class that I store my `dbcontext` configuration settings in because the code I have below repeats all over my project and I want it called from one place.

I also pasted what I created but I'm not sure how to call this when I create an EF connection to my database.

```
using (dbEntities context = new dbEntities())
{
     // these same config settings are the same in each connection to the db I make
     context.Database.CommandTimeout = 9000000;
     context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
     context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

     //do some work here and upload to the db
}

// this is the helper class I created but I'm not sure how to call it when I use the above code
public class dbconfig : DbContext
{
    public dbconfig()
    {
        this.Database.CommandTimeout = 9000000;
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to put that code in your `dbEntities` constructor, not in the constructor of an unrelated class.

Comment: In which kind of application you are using this code ? WPF/web/console ? Also Do you mean to say you also have a class dbEntities inheriting from DbContext?

Comment: @kuldeep I'm using this code in a console app and the class inheriting from dbcontext is my attempt at figuring out how to get this to work in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try following

```
public class dbEntities : DbContext
{
  public dbEntities ()
    : base("someconnectionstring")
  {
    // Get the context related to this DbContext
    var context = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

    // Sets the common properties here
     context.Database.CommandTimeout = 9000000;
     context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
     context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
  }
}
```

However, I must point out that this will switch off the change tracking for your entire application. Should the need arise however, you can again override in at the place where you use dbContext.

Have more look here on [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/auto-detect-changes) in EF.

EDIT

See if you can do following ?

```
public class dbconfig : dbEntities
{
    public dbconfig()
    {
        this.Database.CommandTimeout = 9000000;
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

And then

```
using (var context = new dbConfig())
{
      ///access dbsets
}
```

Comment: That dbEntities class is auto generated code from my app. I used your code in the auto generated class and that seems to work but I was trying to provide a separate class that does the same thing in case the auto generated class gets deleted or something else happens. I wasn't sure how to create a separate dbcontext class to use instead

Comment: In that case (of autogenerated code deleted and so will the context) how will the app communicate to DB at run time? I mean will the code of setting configuration anyway matter then ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe I didn't even think about inheriting the dbentities class